# JSON output after XSLT on IBM Datapower

Tags: json, xslt, ibm-datapower

There is two XSL transformations in IBM Datapower one after another. First of them contains url-open call and returns some ***BINARY NODE***. That node contains .gz archive with JSON doc inside. Second transformation is below:

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" media-type="application/json"/>
<dp:input-mapping type="ffd" href="local:///binaryNode.ffd"/>

<xsl:variable name="input64" select="dp:binary-encode(/object/message/node())"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="alert" dp:type="all">input64<xsl:copy-of select="$input64"/></xsl:message>
   <xsl:variable name="outputJson" select="dp:inflate($input64, 'gzip')"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$outputJson"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Binary node first transforms to Base64 string ($input64) and then unpacks by dp:inflate function. $outputJson variable definitely contains a JSON string. But XSLT output is empty string despite of  instruction `<xsl:copy-of select="$outputJson"/>`. How can I get a JSON on output?

Answer (score 0):

To output something from a XSLT binary you need to wrap it in the "output":

```
<object>
   <message>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$outputJson"/>
   </message>
</object>
```

I would however consider using a context variable instead:

```
<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/JSON/output'" value="$outputJson" />
```